# "reges stellae" or "reges astrum" to evoke self-confident "Star Kings"?

Tags: translation-check

I am writing a story about three "space cowboy" types who call themselves "Star Kings."  They are full of confidence to the point of arrogance.  They also see their adventures as a path to glory and accompanying fame.

EDIT: They consider themselves kings of all the stars.

I have an acronym in mind that would add to the story.  The initials R.A.  for "**r**eges **a**strum" would help the story if I could add those initials to the acronym.  From what I know / have researched, "astrum" would capture the ideas of "star" and "glory" and "constellation" I want to include.

However, I am not sure if "adstrum" or "stellae" would be a better fit.

Comment: @Rafael updated with answer to your comment, thank you.

Comment: There is even a good, ready-made, back story to this: According to Timaeus (by Plato), Stars are indeed immortal Spirits. Some survive severe tests and find their way back to the Empyrean ('Dream of Scipio,' Cicero).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you've settled on ***rēgēs*** for "kings", which is a perfectly good word for that purpose. And to the Romans it would most certainly imply that they were supremely confident, as people at the time did *not* like kings—Caesar and the later emperors specifically avoided the term.

For "of the stars" you have several options, each with their own benefits and drawbacks.

***Sīderum*** (from *sīdus, sīderis*): a poetic term, which can mean "stars", "constellations", "the night sky", or even "the heavens". It's a rather grandiose (and slightly pretentious) word to use in your title…sort of like using a Latin title in English!

***Astrōrum*** or ***Asterum*** (from *astrum, -ī* or *astēr, asteris*): borrowed from Greek *ἄστρον* and *ἀστήρ*, these terms eventually started to replace the native Latin words. *Astrum* was considerably more common than *astēr*, though both would be understood. In Classical times these words were still a bit exotic and found "poet[ically] or in more elevated prose", as Lewis and Short put it, though they were still less poetic than *sīdus*.

*ETA: **astrum** would be a slightly more poetic form than **astrōrum**, with the same meaning.*

***Stellārum*** (from *stella, -ae*): *stella* is the most neutral, standard word for a star or other heavenly body. Calling a single star a *sīdus*, for example, would be somewhat akin to referring to the sky as "the great vault of the heavens" in normal conversation. Planets were *stellae errantes*, comets were *stellae comantes*, and meteors were *stellae lābentes* (or sometimes just *stellae*).

*ETA: **stellum** would be a slightly more poetic form than **stellārum**, with the same meaning.*

***Caelī*** or ***Coelī*** (from *caelum, -ī*): "heaven", or literally "the sky". This is the most arrogant option out of all of these, as "the King of Heaven" or "the King of the Sky" was a title of Jupiter (and later of the Christian God). But if your characters have reached that point, they might find such a title perfect.

Comment: There is the alternative short plural genitive ending *-um* (instead of *-orum*), but I don't know when it can be used. I guess *astrum* is valid too.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta True, that might give a bit of a poetic sound to it. I'll edit.

Comment: @Cerberus I'm not sure I've ever seen it before, but it's mentioned here: *The genitive singular sometimes ends in āī in poetry; the genitive plural sometimes takes the form um instead of ārum.* - https://www.bolchazy.com/Assets/Bolchazy/extras/vergilgrammaticalappendix.pdf

Comment: @Draconis: Interesting! That's new to me.